# What is the right regex for extracting string after first symbol?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

In google data studio I would like to make a `REGEXP_EXTRACT` for getting the string after the first `|` symbol (https://regex101.com/r/w3BqW4/2). I've tried the regex:

```
[|].*?$
```

but this is returning:

```
' | Leren afzaklaarzen Elisio | kalk'
```

So I still need to lose the first `' | '`. Can anyone help me?

**Example:**

Input: `Toral | Leren afzaklaarzen Elisio | kalk`

Output: `Leren afzaklaarzen Elisio | kalk`

Comment: Please share the code you tried to get an idea of what problem you have.

Comment: This is a possible matching pattern. /[|].*?$/

Comment: @AkinOkegbile

with the regex, '[|].*?$' it's returning:  | Leren afzaklaarzen Elisio | kalk. So I still need to lose the first ' | '.

Comment: You have no capture groups, so how are you expecting to extract things?

Comment: Just as one group so, ([|].*$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a capturing group `()` to the ***initial RegEx*** does the trick:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "[|](.*)?$")
```

Adding the suggestion by cricket_007 "*You cannot have "zero or one" of "zero or more" characters*":

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "[|](.*)$")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/fa73be13-e76a-4795-ac02-12b27903fd31) to demonstrate:

[image: 2]]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture every character after the first vertical bar, that would look like this

`\\|(.*)$`

You don't need question mark after a `.*`

Comment: When i'm trying you regex in https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html it's output is the same as the input.

Comment: Well, looking at the REGEXP_EXTRACT documentation, this seems to be want you want

Comment: I only want to group: 'Leren afzaklaarzen Elisio | kalk'

Comment: I see that. Try regex101 again. Add the ungreedy modifier. It works for me